# iOS - Make sure an in app email goes through

Tags: ios, email, sms, verify

If I have an app that sends emails or sms messages to a users friends from within the app how can I check to make sure the message has gone through and sent successfully, or wether or not bad service got in the way of the message successfully sending and what not or can this not be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the result of sending an email from your app you should implement the delegate method `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:result:error`

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
        // email was sent successfully
    } else if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
        // email failed to send
        NSLog(@"mail send error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Be sure to set the the delegate of your `MFMailComposeViewController` to `self`.

[Apple docs reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate)

Of course this only tells you whether the email was successfully *sent*.  There's really no way to know that the email gets *delivered* on the recipient's end.

Comment: SWEET! Thanks so much! Do you know anything about sms for this same thing?

Comment: For SMS it's basically the same, except you'll use a `MFMessageComposeViewController` object and implement the `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` delegate method.